# How to throw custom message to a particular target element in CSHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

Suppose I have one field and I want to throw validation message if its empty, then it can be done by ASP.net framework itself. I just need to have `jquery validation` included in the project and mark the `field as [Required] in viewmodel or model`. But what if I want some error message to be displayed when the user focuses out of the field (humor me on this).

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CreditDetails.CreditCardNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 required" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBox(Model.ModelPropertyPrefixName + "CreditDetails.CreditCardNumber", Model.CreditDetails.CreditCardNumber,
                    new { id = Model.ModelPropertyPrefix + "CreditDetails_CreditCardNumber", @class = "form-control required" })
                @Html.ValidationMessage(Model.ModelPropertyPrefixName + "CreditDetails.CreditCardNumber", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

**Script code in cshtml file**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#CreditDetails_CreditCardNumber")
              .blur(function () {
alert("You focussed out of the field");

        });
    });
</script>
```

Now this alert works perfectly fine. But I want this message to come not as an alert but near the field itself. just like it was coming if I leave the field empty. How to add this alert content to the error bag of creditcard field. So that if I blur out the error message gets displayed just may be beneath the field and not as an script alert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to add a message, so add `<span></span>` tag inside your input div

```
<div class="col-md-10">
@Html.TextBox(Model.ModelPropertyPrefixName + "CreditDetails.CreditCardNumber", Model.CreditDetails.CreditCardNumber,
                    new { id = Model.ModelPropertyPrefix + "CreditDetails_CreditCardNumber", @class = "form-control required" })
                @Html.ValidationMessage(Model.ModelPropertyPrefixName + "CreditDetails.CreditCardNumber", new { @class = "text-danger" })
<span class="blurErrorMessage"></span>
</div>
```

and then

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#CreditDetails_CreditCardNumber")
          .blur(function () {  $('.blurErrorMessage').text("Message error");

    });
});
```

You'll probably need some css to style it

Comment: Don't you think it's more like a work around. Can't I somehow add the message in the validation error bag of that target element? Kindly guide me.

Comment: Can I target `@Html.ValidationMessage(Model.ModelPropertyPrefixName + "CreditDetails.CreditCardNumber", new { @class = "text-danger" })` and utilize this to add error message.

Comment: I've never did something like this. You can try Remote validation, maybe it's what you want. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(v=vs.98).aspx